# How to route very similar URLs to different controller actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working with an MVC4 web application and have ran in to some issues routing that I am not sure how to handle. I want to be able to map my URLs to controller actions but the URLs have no distinguishing factors to assist me with understanding what URL requires what controller actions.

Example of the URL:

- /[product category]
- /[product category]/[product name]
- /[product category]/[product sub category]/[product name]
- /[random content name]

Is there any way I can work this without including an identifier within the URL to map the controller action. For example:

- /pc/[product category]
- /p/[product category]/[product name]
- /p/[product category]/[product sub category]/[product name]
- /c/[random content name]

With this I can map the pc, p, c to the necessary controller but I would prefer to avoid if possible.

Is there a way of achieving what I have outlined?

Comment: So, you want the same route to map to two controllers, without there being any rules as to what maps to what? This sounds like asking for bizarre namespace clashes.

Comment: Kinda yeah when you put it like that :-)

Comment: I believe you'll just have to map indistinguishable URL patterns to a single controller action, and disambiguate based on whichever rules you want there. ASP.NET routing seems pretty married to URL patterns.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible with the built-in routes, but you can extend the RouteBase class to support it.

```
public class ProductRoute : RouteBase {
    private readonly IRouteHandler _routeHandler;

    public ProductRoute(IRouteHandler handler) {
        _routeHandler = handler;
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        string virtualPath = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath + httpContext.Request.PathInfo;

        IDictionary<string, string> routeValues;
        if (TryGetRouteValuesForAlias(virtualPath, out routeValues)) {
            var data = new RouteData(this, _routeHandler);
            foreach (var routeValue in routeValues) {
                data.Values.Add(routeValue.Key, routeValue.Value);
            }

            return data;
        }
        //No route data for alias found, return null, which means that this route doesn't match the path
        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values) {
        string virtualPath = null;
        if (GetVirtualPathForRouteData(values, out virtualPath);) {
            VirtualPathData result = new VirtualPathData(this, match);

            return result;
        }
        //No virtual path found for the route data
        return null;
    }
}
```

We are using something similar in our CMS. The implementation of the functions `GetVirtualPathForRouteData` and `TryGetRouteValuesForAlias` is tied with our solution, so I won't post it here, but I think you get an idea, how it is working.

Essentially the `GetVirtualPathForRouteData` function takes dictionary of route parameters (e.g. controller, action, id) and tries to find an URL for them. The `TryGetRouteValuesForAlias` do the reverse process it takes URL and tries to find a route parameters for it.

**Edit** (sample implementation of the GetVirtualPathForRouteData and TryGetRouteValuesForAlias)

```
//key - url, value - route values
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>> _urls;

public bool TryGetRouteValuesForAlias(string path, out IDictionary<string, string> routeValues) {
    return _urls.TryGetValue(path, out routeValues);
}

public bool GetVirtualPathForRouteData(RouteValueDictionary routeValues, out string virtualPath) {
    foreach (var url in _urls) {
        if (this.CompareValuesLists(url.Value, routeValues)) {
            virtualPath = url.Key;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private bool CompareValuesLists(IDictionary<string, string> urlValues, IDictionary<string, object> routeValues) {
    if (urlValues.Count != routeValues.Count) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach (var key in urlValues.Keys) {
        if (!routeValues.ContainsKey(key)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!string.Equals(urlValues[key], Convert.ToString(routeValues[key]), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Routing data is held in the `_urls`variable. (In our solution we have a little more complicated solution  - instead of the simple variable we are using a DI container to get an instance of a class, that is responsible for loading and caching data from DB)

Comment: Thanks for this information, it is most helpful. I get the idea but I am not 100% sure of the implementation of the methods you outlined. Maybe I am asking alot, but would it be possible for you to email on to me the custom solution you have to enhance my understanding?

Comment: I have added a sample implementation of the methods to the answer. It still isn't a copy&paste solution, but now it should be more clear.